# Can't put hyperlink and general sibling combinator at the same time?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, css-selectors

Hey guys I'm really new to css so I'll try to explain this the best I could.

I'm trying to create an image hyperlink *.link* so that whenever I hover my mouse pointer over it, *.link* and *.picture* "changes" their image. But I still want the hyperlink to be clickable.

```css
.picture {
  background-image: url('imageB1.jpg');
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.link {
  background-image: url('imageA1.jpg');
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.link:hover {
  background-image: url('imageA2.jpg');
}

.link:hover+.picture {
  background-image: url('imageB2.jpg');
}
```

```html
<a href="destination.html">
  <div class="link"></div>
</a>
<div class="picture"></div>
```

The problem with my code is that while *.link* may be clickable, *picture* doesn't change its background-image when I hover on *.link*. I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Move `.picture` inside `<a>` as well

Comment: Thanks! .picture started to change now though I was hoping that only .link will be clickable. Could you help me with that as well? :D

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try this one 
 <a href="destination.html" >
 <div class="link">
  </div>
  </a>
  <div class="picture"></div>



 .picture {
 background-image: url('imageB1.jpg');
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
  display:none;
  }

.link {
background-image: url('imageA1.jpg');
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
display:block;
 }

 .link:hover {
  content: url('imageA2.jpg');
  }

   .link:hover+.picture {
   background-image: url('imageB2.jpg');
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether general sibling combinaton can be select from one sibling but you can do it using different way.

As wrapping both element(**a and div**) to another div element then you can select Selects all **.pictures** classes where the parent is a **.container** class like the below.

```
.picture {
  background-image: url('DSC_0268.jpg');
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.link {
  background-image: url('DSC_0268.jpg');
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.link:hover {
  background-image: url('db 2 assignment schedule.png');
}

.container:hover > .picture {
  background-image: url('db 2 assignment schedule.png');
}
</style>

<div class="container">
<a href="destination.html">
  <div class="link"></div>
</a>
<div class="picture"></div>
</div>
```

look for selectors that you can use in css. [css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

I think this will met what you want to do!.